# Date and time of execution of a program

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How can date and time of execution of a program be loaded at middle of a program.
Every time I use exec date command it seems to ignore everything beneath it.

Comment: Don't use `exec` in that context: it *replaces* the current shell with the command you give it. If you need more specific advice then **post an example of code**.

Comment: echo "HELLO" ;                                                                                       exec date ;                                                                                          echo "HI"                                                                                               You got my point right, I need to print HELLO then date and time of exec time of a program and then HI

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting the code in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help exec`:

```
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
    Replace the shell with the given command.
```

You don't want to replace the current shell (which will prevent script execution from reaching any subsequent commands): just use `date`

```
echo "HELLO"
date
echo "HI"
```